# How to join two tables with three pairs

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables that I want to combine (join) in SQL.

Table 1 Persons:

| Person _Id | First_name | Last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 135790 | John | Smith |
| 246801 | Lucas | Williams |
| 054953 | George | Johnson |
| 460235 | Adam | White |

Table 2 Loans:

| Borrower_Id | resident1_id | resident2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 135790 | 246801 | 054953 |
| 460235 | 054953 | 135790 |
| 054953 | 246801 | 135790 |

The expected result:

| Borrower_FN | Borrower_LN | resident1_FN | resident1_LN | resident2_FN | resident1_LN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | Lucas | Williams | George | Johnson |
| Adam | White | George | Johnson | John | Smith |
| George | Johnson | Lucas | Williams | John | Smith |

How can I join it?

Comment: Just join to the loans table 3 times, once on borrower_id, once on resident1_id, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way you can achieve the result:

```
select p.First_name as Borrower_FN, p.Last_name as Borrower_LN,
 p2.First_name as resident1_FN, p2.Last_name as resident1_LN,
 p3.First_name as resident2_FN, p3.Last_name as resident2_LN
     from Loans l
     inner join Persons p on p.Person_id = l.Borrower_id
     inner join Persons p2 on p2.Person_id = l.resident1_id
     inner join Persons p3 on p3.Person_id = l.resident2_id
```